# Django ImageField changes some characters in the file name unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models, arabic

I am using `ImageField` field in my model with a custom function for the upload path as following:

```
featured_image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=custom_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

where `custom_path` is defined as following:

```
def custom_path(instance, filename):
    return 'post_images/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}'.format(instance.publication_datetime.strftime('%Y'), instance.publication_datetime.strftime('%b'),
                                                instance.slug, filename)
```

The problem is that when I upload a file with a name of `"سائل-أن"` (which is in Arabic), the name gets converted to `"سايل-ان"` which has two different characters from the original name (`"ئـ"` is converted to `"يـ"`, and `"أ"` is converted to `"ا"`).

I think that the problem is with how Django gets the `filename` parameter that is sent to `custom_path` because `slug` won't be modified if it has the same "problematic" name (`"سائل-أن"`).

The letters that get converted are normal Arabic letters that are used millions of times on the internet.

I've searched in Django documentation and source code, but I couldn't know the cause of the problem.

## Edit

I am running my code on a Ubuntu server.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: It looks like this is the code that scrubs file names: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.7/django/utils/text.py#L237. Not sure if the behavior you're seeing is intended or not.

Comment: I am using Python3

Comment: @Blurp I tried to use the code that is inside `get_valid_filename` on the specified string (`"سائل-أن"`), but this didn't reproduce the problem

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @Blurp Django 1.11